# What happened to Joseph's coat of many colors

Tags: history, clothing, yosef, parashat-vayeishev

What happened to Yosef's coat of many colors? I know the brothers gave it to Yakov. But what happened later?
Did he have it in Egypt?
Do we know?

Answer (score 7):

Presumably, it was buried, because there is a Chiyuv D'Oraisa (biblical obligation) to bury the dead. It is a question in the Poskim of how much remains of the dead requires burial, but a significant amount certainly requires burial.

Yaakov was under the impression that the Kesonos Pasim had absorbed a lot of blood from the dead Yosef. That being case, he would have buried it in fulfillment of the Halacha of burying the dead.

Comment: Looking at the commentaries of Rashi, Ibn Ezra, Malbim and others, it is clear that both Yaacov Avinu and Yitzchok Avinu knew that whatever was being presented by the children (sons) was not true or accurate. Yaacov knew a wild animal would never attack & kill his son, Yosef. According to many, Yitzchok knew for certain that Yosef was alive. To assume that Yaacov observed the laws of mourning here and buried the coat of Adam has no basis from the Torah. It is more likely that it would have been put away and ultimately returned to its owner, Yosef.

Comment: And all that said, if your premise is that Yaacov Avinu was being meticulous in observing the laws of mourning regarding what to bury, it would have to follow through with the halachic prohibition against excessive mourning (Shulchan Aruch 394:1-2). Yaacov violated all these prohibitions if you assume he actually believed Yosef was dead. Rather, he was mourning that his beloved son had been taken from him for an indefinite period of time into the future. And that is why he could not be comforted.

Comment: Regarding this subject as it applies in halacha, see, Mourning in Halacha by Rabbi Chaim Benyamin Goldberg, chapter 5:58, Missing Bodies.

Answer (score 2):

https://www.sefaria.org/Avodah_Zarah.11b.3?lang=bi

The Talmud says "Romi has another festival: once in 70 years, they put a healthy man (to represent Esav) on top of a lame man (Yakov); 'Esav' wears the clothes of Adam ha'Rishon, has the skin of R. Yishmael over his face, and the weight of a Zuz of Paz (a very rare type of gold) hanging from his neck;"

Rashi there comments about the clothes
 - והן בגדי חמודות שהיו לעשו

There is an opinion that says this garment Yaakov wore to receive the blessing from his father and passed it down to Yosef.